# Playa tag ignoring child_ids parameter and Low Events parameter

Tags: playa, low-variables

I'm trying to use Low Events in conjunction with a Playa primary tag pair to exclude expired entries from showing up on the site. This is the code I think should work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="home" show_expired="no" limit="1" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" rdf="off"}
    {exp:low_events:entry_ids channel="events" show_passed="no"}{low_events:entry_ids}
      {cf-home-events show_future_entries="yes" limit="3" child_ids="{low_events:entry_ids}"}
        {title}
      {/cf-home-events}
    {/exp:low_events:entry_ids}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The primary issue is the Playa primary tag pair is ignoring the show_passed="no" parameter from the low_events tag. I think the issue has something to do with the Playa tag's "child_ids" parameter because it is not parsing the correct info. For example, the "{low_events:entry_ids}" field outside of the Playa tags excludes passed events. But the "child_ids="{low_events:entry_ids}"" ignores that completely. I tried manually inputting the entry ids into the "child_ids" parameter, but it ignored that too, outputting the same values as before.

Any ideas as to why Playa would be ignoring the Low Events parameter? Or why it would be ignoring the "child_ids" tag parameter?

FYI: Playa 4.3.3 running on Expression Engine 2.5.3. Low Events is version 1.1.1.

Comment: If you hard-code the child IDs, do you get the expected output?

Comment: No. It still includes entries that have passed. The playa tag seems to be completely ignoring the child_ids parameter. I tested with the {low_events:entry_ids} tag directly before the playa field (seen above), and that output correctly. However, the {low_events:entry_ids} inside the playa does not.

Comment: hfrancke - can you add the code above that is erroring for you, when it doesn't include Low Variables, just hard-coded Child IDs? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried substituting `show_passed="no"` with `show_expired="no"` in your Low Events tag? This will apply to the *entry's* expiration date and not the show end event.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to use the Low Events end date so the client does not have to set the date twice.

Comment: OK, from your comment I thought you were trying to look at the entry expiration date rather than the end date: "I'm trying to use Low Events in conjunction with a Playa primary tag pair to exclude expired entries from showing up on the site."